# how to determine the size of memory used by linux kernel on a running system

Tags: linux, ubuntu

What's the easiest way to check the amount of memory used by the linux kernel on a running sytem? In general, does the kernel memory footprint stay the same on a running system under stress?

thx

Comment: What commands have you tried that didn't give the information you week?

Comment: I had seen this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97261/how-much-ram-does-the-kernel-use but was hoping there was a simpler, more straightforward answer

Comment: The accepted answer seems crystal clear to me